# Generating an SSL cert for Azure VM

Tags: azure, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, virtual-machine

I apologize in advance for my ignorance but this is a bit of a learning experience for me. I have create a VM on Azure and opened up ports 80 and 443. An example website on works perfectly fine on Port 80 -
i.e. http://myvm.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/WebApp/WebPage.aspx

So now I'm trying to add TLS to this setup by following the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-secure-web-server#create-a-virtual-machine).

According to this, I should be able to generate an SSL cert, add it to the Azure key vault and inject it into IIS running on the VM thereby adding SSL to any sites on that VM.

But when I go to create the certificate in the key vault, the subject expects a domain name. This is where I'm stuck. I don't have specific domain name and have simply configured a DNS entry for the VM via the portal as that is sufficient for me. So what domain should I supply to generate the certificate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For testing, you can generate a certificate for `myvm.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com`.

Comment: Thanks Lex - I think you're suggesting a self-signed certificate for testing purposes? But for going live, how would I generate a certificate via an authority? I mean do I have to get a separate domain name? Thank you.

Comment: You can only generate self-signed certificate because you don't own `azure.com`. If you want to go live you must switch to your own domain and request certificates for your own domain.

Comment: OK - that's what I was thinking Lex. Thanks for the clarification.